# Simple way to create a new file in Android

Tags: android, file

I have been trying to create a new file, the data is in an Array list:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photos", image_str));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserId", userId));
```

I want to create a file storing `nameValuesPairs`, which is an ArrayList.

How do I create a file in Android??? Preferably an easy way, using array, photos, and others.

Answer (score 0):

To create a file on External storage for saving pictures etc, refer to [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

To create a file on internal storage refer to [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do it.

```
// First make sure we have SD card access 
private boolean ensureSDCardAccess(String directoryPath) {
    File file = new File(directoryPath);
    if (file.exists()) {               // Check if directory already exits 
        return true;
    } else if (file.mkdirs()) {       // Create if doesn't exists already
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Now create file
public void create file(String directoryName, String fileName)
{
   String directoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + directoryName;
   if (ensureSDCardAccess(directoryPath)) {
        String filePath = directoryPath + fileName;
        File file = new File(filePath);
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            // Write to the file             
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Panel", "FileNotFoundException", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Panel", "IOEception", e);
        }
}
```